# ActiveRecord saving: differences in Rails 3.2.19 and Rails 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 identical projects: with Rails 3.2.19 and updated to Rails 4.2.0beta4.
When I try to do `Foo.create!` in Rails 3.2 and Rails 4.2 I see diffirent queries in the Rails Console log.

Rails 3.2 output:

```
INSERT INTO `foos` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `column_1`,`column_2`, ...) VALUES ('2014-11-19 11:20:28.391649', '2014-11-19 11:20:28.391649', NULL, NULL, ...)
```

Rails 4.2 output:

```
INSERT INTO `foos` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-11-19 11:20:28.391649', 545662, '2014-11-19 11:20:28.391649')
```

Please explain why different Rails versions execute different queries and why did it so?

Comment: Because they've changed the code to make it more efficient. You can find out about it [here](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2014/02/19/adequaterecord-pro-like-activerecord.html) It's not really a question for SO though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related with [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) which are enabled by default in the 4.x version.
Taking the example from the documentation:

```
class PeopleController < ActionController::Base
  # This will raise an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes exception because it's using mass assignment
  # without an explicit permit step.
  def create
    Person.create(params[:person])
  end

  # This will pass with flying colors as long as there's a person key in the parameters, otherwise
  # it'll raise an ActionController::ParameterMissing exception, which will get caught by
  # ActionController::Base and turned into that 400 Bad Request reply.
  def update
    person = current_account.people.find(params[:id])
    person.update_attributes!(person_params)
    redirect_to person
  end

  private
    # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters is just a good pattern
    # since you'll be able to reuse the same permit list between create and update. Also, you
    # can specialize this method with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
    end
end
```

in the `person_params` method you need to allow all the parameters you want to be changed.